# Keep Bootstrap nav dropdown from opening only on small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a bootstrap navbar where some of the items have a dropdown links.
However, for small screens (< 768px), I want to keep the menu primarily based on icons without the dropdown.

So far I managed to keep the submenu from showing in small screens with *xs-hidden* and *event.stopPropagation()* on click. However, this also disables the submenu in larger screen sizes, which I don't want.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior only for small screens without adding a repeated menu item and hide/show it according to screen width?

Relevant code is below.

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="/">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope visible-xs"></i>
    <span>Messages</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown" id="navbar-admin-dropdown">
  <a href="/" class="dropdown-toggle disabled-nav-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-cogs visible-xs"></i>
    <span>Admin</span>
    <b class="caret hidden-xs"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu hidden-xs">
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="/">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off visible-xs"></i>
    <span>Logout</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

CSS

The **nav-item** is just for aligning and layout of each individual link. It doesn't affect dropdown functionality.

JS

```
$('.disabled-nav-item').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, the problem comes with `event.stopPropagation();`.

You could use jQuery to detect the screen width and if it is smaller than your target size, apply the `event.stopPropagation();`.

```
$('.disabled-nav-item').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/oPCpdAJf1M)